# Rails: Tilde usage in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I just stumbled across this line in a HAML/Rails form:

```
~ f.input :content, label: false
```

What does the tilde do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Whitespace Preservation: ~](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#tilde):

> `~` works just like `=`, except that it runs
>   [`Haml::Helpers#find_and_preserve`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#find_and_preserve-instance_method) on its input. For example,
>
> `~ "Foo\n<pre>Bar\nBaz</pre>"`
>
> is the same as:
>
> `= find_and_preserve("Foo\n<pre>Bar\nBaz</pre>")`
>
> and is compiled to:
>
> `Foo <pre>Bar&#x000A;Baz</pre>`